# Doctrine WhereHas Equivalent

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Here are some tables for a simple Purchase/Product relationship:

```
Purchase
- id
- status_id

Product
- id
- name

ProductPurchase
- id
- product_id
- purchase_id
- quantity
```

**I need to query all `Purchases` that have a `status_id = X`, and that have at least one `ProductPurchase` where the `product_id = X`**

I am from the Laravel environment, so what I was doing before was something like:

```
$purchases = Purchase::where('status_id',$s_id)
    ->whereHas(['productPurchases' => function ($query) use($product_id) {
        $query->where('product_id',$product_id)
    }])->get();
```

However I can't find any similar solution into the doctrine documentation and I am sure that I don't have the correct keywords to make my search...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I changed `product_id` to `Y` in my answer, since I assume the `status_id` and `product_id` are not the same thing/value here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [a doctrine query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) you can do that like this:

```
$status_id = X;
$product_id = Y;
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->innerJoin('p.productPurchase', 'pp')
    ->where('p.status = :status_id')
    ->andWhere('pp.product = :product_id')
    ->setParameters([
        'status_id' => $status_id,
        'product_id' => $product_id,
    ]);
);
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
return $query->getResult();
```

So `p` is your purchase and the `innerjoin` on `ProductPurchase` (alias `pp`) where `pp.product_id` set to `Y` makes sure we only get those purchases that have such relationship/association.