# Doctrine ORM: Excluding Records Based on Values of Nested Relationships

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

**Quick Overview**

Hey guys! I'm working on an app that has the ability for an `Order` to contain multiple `OrderStatus` which then have a relationship with the `Status` entity themselves. Here's a sort of simplified ERD diagram:

[image: ERD Diagram of an order and the link table created for statuses]

**The Question:**

What I want to do is get `Orders` where the last `OrderStatus` doesn't have a status matching a specific tag, which is a string. So no orders whose last `OrderStatus` has a `Status` with a tag of "fulfilled", "pending", etc. I'm pretty much using `OrderStatus` as a sort of link table because I need to be able to track the time between status changes / keep a history. Otherwise I would have generated it as a many to many relationship.

**Simplified Entity Definitions:**

Order.php

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OrderRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`order`")
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=OrderStatus::class, mappedBy="cust_order", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $orderStatuses;
...
```

OrderStatus.php

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OrderStatusRepository::class)
 */
class OrderStatus
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Status::class, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Order::class, inversedBy="orderStatuses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $cust_order;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    public function __construct(Order $order = null, Status $status = null) {
        $this->created = new DateTime("NOW");
        $this->cust_order = $order; 
        $this->status = $status; 
    }...
```

Status.php

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=StatusRepository::class)
 */
class Status
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $tag;
```

I would appreciate any help I could get! I'm not the most familiar with more complex queries like this. I'm fairly certain this may be resolved somehow with sub queries using the query builder but I can't quite wrap my head around how to go about doing that because I rarely ever have to use sub queries.

Thank you for any help I can get!

Edit:
Here's something that I attempted but all this really did was filter out the actual statuses themselves. I need the whole Order to be filtered out:

```php
            $qb
                ->innerJoin("e.orderStatuses", "os")
                ->innerJoin("os.status", "s")
                ->andWhere("s.tag IN (:nonPendingStatuses)")
                ->setParameter("nonPendingStatuses", [
                    "new","in_progress","awaiting_pickup","fulfilled"
                ], \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);
```

***Update***

Here is my current attempt. I think I'm close but I don't quite have it yet. Currently getting an array to string conversion error.

```php
        /**
         * Get orders awaiting fulfillment 
         */

         public function getActiveOrders(){
             $qb = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder("o");
            //  $sub_qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
             $qb-> 
                andWhere(
                    $qb->expr()->notIn(
                        $qb->select('os.id')
                        ->from("App\Entity\OrderStatus", "os")
                        ->andWhere("os.custOrder = o")
                        ->orderBy("os.created", "desc")
                        ->setMaxResults(1)
                        ->getQuery()->getResult()
                        ,
                        $qb
                        ->select('s.id')
                        ->from("App\Entity\Status", "s")
                        ->orWhere("s.tag = 'fulfilled'")
                        ->orWhere("s.tag = 'pending'")
                        // ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in("s.tag",":exclusions"))
                        // ->setParameter(":exclusions", ['pending', 'fulfilled'])
                        ->getQuery()->getResult()
                    )
                )
                ;
                $query = $qb->getQuery();
            return $query->getResult();
         }
```

***Update***
Here's a SQL query of what I'm trying to implement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   `order` o
WHERE  (SELECT status_id
        FROM   order_status os
        WHERE  os.cust_order_id = o.id
        ORDER  BY os.created DESC
        LIMIT  1) NOT IN (SELECT id
                          FROM   status s
                          WHERE  s.tag IN ( 'pending', 'fulfilled' ));
```

Comment: "ability for an Order to contain multiple OrderStatus" means `order.order_statuses` is sufficient column.

Comment: @Tpojka well in this case the only relevant `OrderStatus` is going to be the last one which we can get by sorting by the created Datetime attribute.

Comment: Can [accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849108/doctrine-wherehas-equivalent#answer-40849360) help in some way?

Comment: @Tpojka that answer looks like a more simple join. I'm wanting to filter out the `Order` itself if its last `OrderStatus` is associated with a `Status` that has a tag of like "pending" or whatever else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to do is get Orders where the last OrderStatus doesn't have a status matching a specific tag

I assume the latest `OrderStatus` will be selected based on the higher `created` column value.

To pick latest `OrderStatus` for each order we will need [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) logic. To pick only one latest record for each group/order

In pure SQL it can be achieved via [window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)) or [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106582/doctrine-query-language-get-max-latest-row-per-group/46233080#46233080)

SQL

```
SELECT o.*
FROM `order` o
JOIN order_status os ON o.id = os.cust_order_id
LEFT JOIN order_status os1 ON os.cust_order_id = os1.cust_order_id
                           AND os.created < os1.created
JOIN STATUS s ON s.id = os.status_id
WHERE os1.created IS NULL
AND s.tag NOT IN ('pending')
```

and in query builder it can written as

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->innerJoin("o.orderStatuses", "os")
    ->innerJoin("os.status", "s")
    ->leftJoin(
        'Bundle\Entity\OrderStatus',
        'os1',
        'WITH',
        'os.cust_order = os1.cust_order AND os.created < os1.created'
    )
    ->where('os1.created IS NULL')
    ->andWhere("s.tag NOT IN (:pendingStatus)")
    ->setParameter("pendingStatus", ["pending"], \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: You have literally no idea how long I was stuck with this particular problem. You like actually just saved me here haha. I was starting to feel hopeless! 

Thank you so much!!!! Bounty well earned!